# Allow One Function Call (leetcode)

Tags: javascript, function, environment-variables, global-variables

here is link to this exercise [text](https://leetcode.com/problems/allow-one-function-call/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=30-days-of-javascript)
can someone tell me why should i place `res` variable inside function `once` ? like this :

```
var once = function(fn) {

let isCalled = false

    return function(...args){
        if (isCalled){
            return undefined
        }
        else{
            isCalled = true
            return fn(...args)          
        }
    }
};
```

why it is'n working properly when i place `res` variable outside function like :

```
let isCalled = false

var once = function(fn) {
    return function(...args){
        if (isCalled){
            return undefined
        }
        else{
            isCalled = true
            return fn(...args)          
        }
    }
};
```

the second code example outputs : `[]` instead of 140 in second test case. which input is
`(a,b,c) => (a * b * c) [[5,7,4],[2,3,6],[4,6,8]]`

Answer (score 2):

In the first code example, the **isCalled** variable is placed inside the closure returned by the once function. This ensures that each instance of the returned function (**onceFn**) has its own separate **isCalled** variable, allowing it to track whether it has been called independently. This approach correctly returns undefined after the first call, as expected.

In the second code example, where the **isCalled** variable is declared outside the **once** function, it becomes a global variable shared across all invocations of **once(fn)**. This leads to unexpected behavior because once it's set to **true** after the first call, it remains **true** for all subsequent calls to **onceFn**, even when you intend to call fn again.